# Line break and indentation in AucTeX

Tags: indentation, auctex, line-break, visual-line-mode

I am using AucTeX in combination with `visual-line-mode` but sometimes I find it somewhat confusing that a broken line does not follow the "current indentation" which makes it harder to see environments. In other words a "too long line" is indented by a few characters but the parts which had to be broken start a the left of the buffer.

Is there a way to get automated line breaks where the "broken parts of the lines" have the same indentation?